# getting input from user for different types of data and storing it as an object in an ArrayList in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I need to get the input from the user for my "MailCostumer" class.
as you can see there are 3 types: String, int and boolean.

this is the class:

```
class MailCostumer {
    private String name;
    private int id;
    private String address;
    private boolean isPack;

    public MailCostumer(String name, int id, String address, boolean isPack) {
        this.name=name;
        this.id=id;
        this.address=address;
        this.isPack=isPack;
    }


/*in the rest of the class there are the set and get methods
  for class fields, if you need to see them, I will post them.*/
```

My ArrayList is in the class "Queue", like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Queue 
{
    private ArrayList<MailCostumer> waiting = new ArrayList<MailCostumer>();
    private Boolean isEmpty;

    public Queue ()
    {
        this.waiting = new ArrayList<MailCostumer>();
        this.isEmpty=true;      
    }

    public void addClient(MailCostumer MC)
    {
        this.waiting.add(MC);
        this.isEmpty=false;
    }

    public void delClient(MailCostumer MC)
    {
        if(waiting.size()!=0)
        {
            this.waiting.remove(0);
            if(waiting.size()==0)
            {
                this.isEmpty=true;
            }
        }
     }
```

and this is my main class with the main method:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Costumer 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        MailCostumer c1 = new MailCostumer("gabriel", 1234, "ashqelon", true);
        MailCostumer c2 = new MailCostumer("tal", 1235, "ashdod", true);
        Queue q1 = new Queue();

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            c1.setName(scan.nextLine());


        }

        q1.addClient(c1);
        q1.addClient(c2);
        System.out.println(q1.waiting.get(1).getName());

    }
}
```

my question is, how do i get input from the user about different types of data and storing them in my "waiting" ArrayList, as an object of "MailCostumer"?
i need only the ones that isPack==true to be added to the Queue.
im trying to do this from the 'main' method ofcourse, but with no luck.
the 'c1 and c2' i have build, i need the user to input this information.

Comment: you may have misspelled `MailCustomer` to `MailCostumer`

Answer (score 0):

You can have the user type in a line :

> gabriel 1234 ashqelon true

And write your for loop like this (note the extra `hasNextLine` condition)
This will check that the user typed 4 space separated words and that the last one is `"true"`. In that case it will append a new object to the `c1` queue.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5 && scan.hasNextLine(); i++) {
    String line = scan.nextLine();
    String[] data = line.split(" ");
    if (data.length() == 4 && "true".equals(data[3])) {
        q1.addClient(new MailCostumer(
             data[0],
             Integer.parseInt(data[1]),
             data[2],
             true
        );
    }
}
```

Third option make a static construction method in `MailCostumer` that takes a line as argument. That's good design because code specific to generating a `MailCostumer` object should be packaged in the class and not in `main` :

```
public static MailCostumer valueOf(String line) {
    String[] data = line.split(" ");
    if (data.length() == 4 && "true".equals(data[3])) {
        return new MailCostumer(
             data[0],
             Integer.parseInt(data[1]),
             data[2],
             true
        );
    }
    return null;
}
```

The for loop would look very lean then

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5 && scan.hasNextLine(); i++) {
    String line = scan.nextLine();
    MailCostumer c = MailCostumer.valueOf(line);
    if (c != null)
        q1.addClient(c);
}
```